# PhpStorm cursor disappears after using Find/Replace on Windows 10?

Tags: php, phpstorm, jetbrains-ide

I'm using PhpStorm (v 10.0.3) on Windows 10. Anytime I use Find/Replace, the cursor (text marker) disappears from the screen and the code becomes uneditable. I usually have to restart the editor to fix this.

Is this a known issue and can I get a fix?

Comment: Perhaps you could edit your question to include further details about your installations in order to help us better answer your question. Do you have any plugins/extensions installed in PHPStorm? Which version of it are you using? Tip: You could try searching Google for something like "phpstorm known issues", and see if your particular issue has already been reported.

Comment: It is version 10.0.3

Comment: How is this related to programming problems? Shouldn't this be asked at the vendor's help website?

Comment: @Mjh Not necessarily; questions about programming tools are on-topic, here.

Comment: yes... I am also having this problem whenever i create new file in project explorer. This is actually a bug which I faced in PHPStorm, Android Studio and PyCharm. The temporary solution to this is just restart your IDE. But that's really annoying.

Comment: I also have this problem after text search. Switching to a browser (or another program), type something and switching back to PhpStorm makes is work again. But it's annoying!

Answer (score 0):

You're unlikely to find much support for such an old version.

I found the following tip

add this to your /bin/idea.properties

```
actionSystem.suspendFocusTransferIfApplicationInactive=false
```

Also make sure you have the latest JRE installed.

Other then that my only suggestion would be to upgrade to the 2017 version which has various bug fixes (including this bug) and some new great features for OOP PHP.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem on WebStorm, for me, caused by the terminal window, to fix it, go to terminal and write a command on it(ls for example), then reduce the terminal, go back to the editor, the cursor will be visible.